# how to set width according to thead in table format structure?

Tags: html, css

i am working on table structure html and i want to set my design in my stucture!!
i have get issue my table format width is set according to body content !

My question is how can i set width accrding to header ?
here is my code.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Document name</td>
      <td>Category</td>
      <td>Sub category</td>
      <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Indisoft – RX Office and Thinagee- 401K Payment </td>
      <td>admin</td>
      <td>admin-sub</td>
      <td>published</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcICV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `style` on any of the `td` or `th` tags in the `thead`, and it will apply to all the cells in the column.

In the example below I've used an inline style, but that is not necessary. You could use CSS classes for that as well.

Also, you should replace the `td`'s in the `thead` with `th` elements.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px">Document name</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Sub category</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Indisoft – RX Office and Thinagee- 401K Payment </td>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>admin-sub</td>
        <td>published</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set style width for each column, in other case it will resize to body size.

For example:

```css
table {
border: solid 1px #000;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 200px;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100px;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}
table td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 150px;
    border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Document name</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Sub category</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Indisoft – RX Office and Thinagee- 401K Payment </td>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>admin-sub</td>
        <td>published</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```